# Display an item behind text and drop down menu

Tags: html, css, image, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme and have changed my background image.

I now want to display an image on top of the white background (where the content is displayed).

I have done this by using the following code:

```
img style="position: absolute; top:244px; left: 220px;" src="http://www.tgon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/strans1.png"
```

This looks exactly how I want it to, but it has a problem.  The site has a drop down menu, when you scroll down the menu it will disappear when your mouse moves over the image which is displayed behind.

Can anyone help me to move the image back to overlay the background on every page?

I have tried using `z-index` without any success.

This is the site that I want to apply the image to: http://www.tgon.co.uk/

Here is an example of the problem I am having: http://www.tgon.co.uk/info/languages/french/

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The image also blocks any links that are 'behind' the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do is to:

1. Remove the '`position:absolute`' from the image. - this is what cause you the overlapping problem.
2. Add '`margin-top: -107px;`' to the image. - this will push the image up to where you want it.

Anyhow, I didn't understand why didn't you use 'background' css property for this.
You could have just do this:

```
#primary {
    background: #fff url('http://www.tgon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/strans1.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Avisho.  I am trying to add it to the CSS as you suggested.  It does display at the correct height, but it is too far over to the left.  Please could you give me the correct syntax to shift it to the right?

Comment: What you see too far over to the left are your old <img> tags.
Remove this:
`<p><img style="position: absolute; top:244px; left: 220px;" src="http://www.tgon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/strans1.png"><br>
<img style="position: absolute; top:244px; left: 160px;display: none;" src="http://www.tgon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/strans2.png"></p>`

Comment: Thanks Avisho.  The code I used to fix this issue is 

#secondary {
 background: #fff url('http://www.tgon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/stransboth.png') no-repeat;

Comment: Ah, I think I spoke too soon.  This fix now displays the image in the right hand margin (widgit area).  It only needs to display in the main content window...

Comment: Solved:

#primary,
#secondary {
 background: #fff;
 float: left;
}
#primary {
 clear: both;
 margin: 150px 15px 0 0;
 width: 692px;
 background: #fff url('http://www.tgon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/stransboth.png') no-repeat;
}
#secondary {
 margin:  260px 0 0 2px;
 overflow: visible;
 width: 251px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
#branding { z-index: 1001;}
#inner-wrapper { z-index: 1000;}
```

Since the `header` is created before the `#inner-wrapper` div, you will need to apply a higher `z-index` to `header` compared to div#inner-wrapper`.

**EDIT**
Check the screenshot of the developer console view of your markup:

[image]

Just setting the `z-index` right for `header` & `div#inner-wrapper` did it for me.
Let's fix this then I'll be glad to help you set the image right.

Comment: Sorry but I tried to do this and couldn't find the #inner-wrapper to add the z-index.  The other two suggestions to add it to the CSS seem to work, however they are not in the correct position.  Any chance you could help with the syntax for adjusting the pictures location?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this image:
And add this css:

> #content {
>
> background-image:url("http://www.tgon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/strans1.png");
>
> background-repeat:no-repeat }

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Shehzad.  I am trying your way and it seems to be working.  However, the image is now not in the correct place.  What is the correct syntax to set it in the same place I was putting it with my code? (top:244px; left: 220px;)

Comment: you can use background-position css